# What's the most informative way to create a mouse movement visualization?

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouse, visualization, heatmap

Hope this is the right place to ask.

Background: I've been playing osu! a lot recently and decided to create a visualization based on my mouse (actually tablet, but lets keep it what the OS thinks the movement is) movement. Decided to shoot for Java, as there was a [really cool guy who did a library for global mouse events](http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/) which made this entire thing a 5-class project.

Now the situation: I have a simple GUI that allows me to start and stop recording, reset the stored motion data , show debug info and exit. Everything's working - but what do I do with my data now?

My main data set is basically an ArrayList of instances of the following class:

```
package com.gmail.zkfreddit.mousetracker;

import de.ksquared.system.mouse.MouseEvent;

public class MouseMotionData {   
    public final long time;
    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public MouseMotionData(MouseEvent e) {
        time = System.nanoTime();
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MouseMotionData{time=" + time + ",x=" + x + ",y=" + y + "}";
    }
}
```

However, I'm clueless as to how I could visualize this data. [I tried drawing lines](http://puu.sh/cARov/d792b77586.png), but it looks more like some drawing by a 5 year old...

(In case you're interested about the circles in the middle, osu has a gameplay element called "spinner" - that should explain everything ;).)

I also thought of doing a Heatmap - created a double array of my screen pixel dimensions and tried to fill it with values representing heat, but due to how mouse events are processed, this generates points and not lines. And filling in the lines, considering that there are around ~50000 points per visualization + generating heat data based on these lines, seems to be a gigantic task that a standard desktop PC cannot handle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `de.ksquared.system.mouse.MouseEvent;`?? What GUI library are you using?

Comment: No actual GUI library (aside from Swing). I'm using Kristian Kralic's global mouse listener, [found here](http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/). I can paste the other code in the original question, but I think it misses the point - this is just about what I can do with the data.

Comment: What’s the purpose the visualization shall serve? Aesthetics? Analyzing and improving your gameplay? …?

Comment: Aesthetics primarly, it was an idea I had while playing and decided to program something based on it. I'm planning to distribute it on the game's official forums when it's done, for everybody to use. Just a side project for self-experience that introduced me into data visualization, as I never did something in this direction. Edit: If I want to analyze my gameplay, I could just watch a replay, as the game keeps every play and records a replay itself. It just doesn't create a pleasing visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is an idea of mine. It’s a little bit heavy on linear algebra, but I imagine the result to be informative and visually pleasing:

Discretize your samples into a grid of n cells, each maybe 20x20px.
Define *a(i,j)* to be the number of times the mouse moved from cell *i* directly to cell *j*. Remove all cells *j* where *a(i)(j)=0* for all *i* (color them black). Then set *x(j)* as the average of all *x(i)* where *a(i)(j)* is not zero. This leaves you with a (large) homogenous system of linear equations determining the values of all the *x*. Compute some non-constant solution and map the values to color hues for the respective cells. At the end you might want to add some gaussian blur.